# App crash If popViewController while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

Hello I have `UIViewController` inside `UINavigationController` which has a `UITableView` in it. I'm reseting my data model when user tap back button (which triggers `popViewController` function of `UINavigationController`). If I `popViewController` , while scrolling `UITableView`, App crashes on `cellForRowAt` function. What can cause this problem?

**cellForRowAt** function:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, TableView... {

var myChecksModel: MyChecksModel!
.
.
.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell: MyChecksListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as? MyChecksListTableViewCell ??
    MyChecksListTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
let check = self.myChecksModel.chequeList[indexPath.row]
cell.myChecksData = check
return cell
}
```

**Back Button**

```
@objc func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myChecksModel.resetModel()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```

**Reset Model Function**

```
class MyChecksModel: Codable {
var chequeList: [MyClass] = []
func resetModel() {
self.chequeList = []
}
```

Comment: Show the code of     `self.myChecksModel.resetModel()`  There must be a problem

Comment: If you are removing element from array , which is used as tableview datasource , you should avoid this.

Comment: Or in cell for row method check `self.myChecksModel.chequeList.count > indexPath.row` other wise just return cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is crashing because of

> index out of bound

You should call

```
self.myChecksModel.resetModel()
```

In

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

      self.myChecksModel.resetModel()
}
```